# proper coding of an editing loop in access vba

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba

I have a form access that is accepting data.
I have a field I want to ensure the user places an "a" or "q" into.
Assuming they do place an "a" (or "A") or "q" (or "Q") I want to accept that field and upshift it.
if they place anything else I want to reject it (possibly changing the value to something like "?") and require the fix.
They should not be able to leave the field until correct.
OR
I need to learn the better/correct way to do this.
Can you advise or point me so I learn to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the textbox you want to do this, go to the `Data` tab on the `Property Sheet`

There is a property called `Validation Rule`.  For the situation you described you want to say `= "Q" or "A"`.  Access I believe handles the lower case automatically in this property.

There is another property called `Validation Text` where you can place the message you want to display when the text field isn't a "Q" or an "A"

Comment: Next part ...

so if I validate it is a "q" or "Q" or "a" or "A", how do I then upshift it to make it a "Q" or "A"?

I tried
    Private Sub seat_gender_AfterUpdate() 
    Me.seat_gender = UCase(Me.seat_gender) 
    End Sub

without success.

I closer, just not "there" yet.

Answer (score 0):

Next part ... so if I validate it is a "q" or "Q" or "a" or "A", how do I then upshift it to make it a "Q" or "A"? I tried

```
Private Sub seat_gender_AfterUpdate() 
Me.seat_gender = UCase(Me.seat_gender) 
End Sub
```

without success. I closer, just not "there" yet. –